# ¿Como puedo imprimir mi expresión aritmetica de forma que si la ingreso 5+2*4/2 me la vaya imprimiendo operacion por operacion?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

De esta forma quiero que la vaya imprimiendo 
Siguiendo el ejemplo de arriba.
5+2*4/2,5+8/2,5+4,9.
Tengo parte del código, pero me imprime todo de un golpe.
como se puede ver en el codigo, esto solo me lo imprime de un golpe, quisiera que pudieran orientarme para poder resolver esto.

```
String Calcular = String
    Calcular="123+98-79/2*5";
    int CuentaOperadores = 0;
    ArrayList<Caracteres> operadores = new ArrayList<>();
    for(
    int i = 0; i<Calcular.length();i++)

    {
        if (Calcular.charAt(i) == '+' || Calcular.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                Calcular.charAt(i) == '*' || Calcular.charAt(i) == '/') {
            CuentaOperadores++;  //Calcula el numero de operaciones en el String
            operadores.add(Calcular.charAt(i));  //agrega los operadores al ArrayList
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Return Value :");
    String[] obtener = Calcular.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/", CuentaOperadores +
            1);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(obtener[0]);
    int num2 = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(
    int i = 1;
    i<obtener.length;i++)

    {
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(obtener[i]);
        char operador = operadores.get(j);
        if (operador == '+') {
            num1 = num1 + num2;
        } else if (operador == '-') {
            num1 = num1 - num2;
        } else if (operador == '/') {
            num1 = num1 / num2;
        } else {
            num1 = num1 * num2;
        }
        j++
    }
    System.out.println(num1);   // imprime el resultado
```

Comment: Cuando dices que la ingresas, ¿es desde consola? Si fuese un String podrías cortar por el símbolo matemático que quieres y, para el par de números afectados por ella, parsearlos a integer y hacer la operación. Luego, se podría mandar el resultado concatenado con el resto de la expresión por pantalla.

Comment: imprimiendo? significa que estás escribiendo código? Qué has hecho, entonces? En qué lenguaje? En qué falla? Y nada tiene que ver ser nuevo con poner código.

Comment: Hola Zinue, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Como ya te han comentado debes agregar el lenguaje que usas, el código y duda concreta. Como comenta Alfabravo, que seas nuevo no impide que coloques código. Copia tu código **como texto**, pégalo en la pregunta, luego lo seleccionas todo y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor, con eso se formateará adecuadamente. No lo agregues como imágenes o mediante links externos. Si tienes problemas con el formateo, tu pega el código y dejalo como puedas y ya te ayudaremos a formatearlo. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] también. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias, si es que no entendía del todo del teléfono como agregarlo, pero ya agregue el código, espero ser mas claro en mi duda, gracias.

Comment: por favor tomate el tiempo en leer el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Y agrega la etiqueta del lenguaje en el que esta esto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ese tipo de problemas lo más natural es usar recursión. El siguiente código solo funciona con enteros,se ve extenso pero es porque hay bastante código repetido por simplicidad.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class Calculadora{

    public String reducir(String expresion){

        // patron para buscar expresion binaria: a+b,a-c,a*b,a/b
        Pattern operacionBinaria = Pattern.compile("^\\d+[+|\\-|*|\\/]\\d+$");

        Matcher matcherOperacionBinaria = operacionBinaria.matcher(expresion);

        if(matcherOperacionBinaria.find()){
            // es una operacion binaria, se resuelve y se devuelve el resultado
            if(expresion.contains("*")){//es multiplicacion
                //separar los numeros
                String[] partes = expresion.split("\\*");
                //multiplicar ambas partes y devolver el resultado como cadena
                return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(partes[0]) * Integer.parseInt(partes[1]));
            }
            if(expresion.contains("/")){
                //separar los numeros
                String[] partes = expresion.split("\\/");
                //dividir ambas partes y devolver el resultado como cadena
                return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(partes[0]) / Integer.parseInt(partes[1]));
            }
            if(expresion.contains("+")){
                //separar los numeros
                String[] partes = expresion.split("\\+");
                //sumar ambas partes y devolver el resultado como cadena
                return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(partes[0]) + Integer.parseInt(partes[1]));

            }
            if(expresion.contains("-")){
                //separar los numeros
                String[] partes = expresion.split("-");
                //restar ambas partes y devolver el resultado como cadena
                return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(partes[0]) - Integer.parseInt(partes[1]));

            }

        }



        //primero buscamos las operaciones de mayor jerarquia (multiplicacion y division)
        Pattern multiplicacionDivision = Pattern.compile("\\d+[*|\\/]\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = multiplicacionDivision.matcher(expresion);

        //si hay una multiplicacion o division
        if(matcher.find()){
            String expresionSuperior = matcher.group(0);

            String primeraParte = expresion.substring(0,expresion.indexOf(expresionSuperior));

            String segundaParte = expresion.substring(primeraParte.length() + expresionSuperior.length());


            //imprimir resultado intermedio
            String resultado = primeraParte+ reducir(expresionSuperior) + segundaParte;
            System.out.println(resultado);

            //llamada recursiva a reducir
            return reducir(primeraParte+ reducir(expresionSuperior) + segundaParte);
        }


        // si no hay multiplicaciones o divisiones entonces se procesan las sumas y restas

        //patron para buscar sumas y restas
        Pattern sumaResta = Pattern.compile("\\d+[+|\\-]\\d+");

        Matcher sumaRestaMatch = sumaResta.matcher(expresion);
        sumaRestaMatch.find();
        //se encuentra la primera suma o resta
        String sumaOResta = sumaRestaMatch.group(0);
        // dividimos la expresion en dos partes

        //la primera parte contiene lo que esta antes de la suma o resta
        String primeraParte = expresion.substring(0,expresion.indexOf(sumaOResta));

        //la segunda parte contiene lo que esta despues de la suma o resta
        String segundaParte = expresion.substring(sumaOResta.length());

        //imprimir resultado intermedio
        String resultado = primeraParte+ reducir(sumaOResta) + segundaParte;
        System.out.println(resultado);
        //llamada recursiva a reducir
        return reducir(primeraParte+ reducir(sumaOResta) + segundaParte);
    }
}
public class Test{

    public static void main(String... args){

      Calculadora calculadora = new Calculadora();
      String resultado = calculadora.reducir("2*2+1+2/2");
      System.out.println(resultado);

    }
}
```

Practicamente funciona así:

1. se evalúa si la expresión es binaria (a+b,a-b,a*b,a/b), si lo es se calcula y se retorna el resultado
2. Si no es binaria entonces se busca la operacion de mayor jerarquía (multiplicación o división)
3. Si hay una multiplicacion o division la extrae y hace una llamada recursiva a la función reducir()
4. Si no hay multiplicaciones o divisiones entonces procesa las sumas y restas
5. En cada return imprime el paso intermedio

Comment: gracias, esto me acaba de ayudar mucho. gracias.