# Valorizar expresiones ingresadas por usuarios en C#

Tags: c#

Amigos, en un programa ocurre lo siguiente:

1. El programa contiene cinco variables decimales cuyos valores se determinan dentro del programa (x01=100.10, x02=50.50, x03=40.00, x04=25.35 y x05=10.00).
2. El programa solicita al usuario una expresión en base a esas cinco variables. Esta es una expresión que cada usuario ingresa y por tanto puede tomar cualquier forma, dependiendo de lo que usuario exprese en su registro. Por ejemplo, un usuario podría ingresar y pedir valorizar : (x01+x02+x03+x04-x05). Otro usuario podría ingresar: (2*x01+x02-x05). Otro usuario podría solicitar: (x01-2*x02+x03+x04). Y así, estas expresiones dependen de la solicitud de cada usuario según la expresión que consignen.

No encuentro la forma de poder valorizar estas expresiones a través de C#, donde, como mencioné antes, la expresión no se conoce hasta que el usuario lo consigna en plena ejecución del programa. He intentado descomponer usando el método String con Split pero no logro poder rearmar la expresión genérica para lograr valorizar o determinar el valor numérico de las expresiones.

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego código que implementa combinaciones de suma y resta:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    class Program
    {
        private Dictionary<string,decimal> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

        public Program(){
            // inicializar diccionarioi con 3 variables x1...x3
            this.dictionary.Add("x1",100);
            this.dictionary.Add("x2",200);
            this.dictionary.Add("x3",300);
        }

        public void EvaluateExpression(string expression){

            // patron para buscar tokens que empiecen con el signo - o + (opcional) seguido de una
            // x y un número ej : -x1+x2, x2+x3+x4, etc.
            string pattern = @"(-|\+)?x\d+";

            Regex rg = new Regex(pattern); 

            // obtener todos los match en la expresión
            var matches = rg.Matches(expression);

            decimal total = 0;

            // recorrer cada token obtenido
            for (int count = 0; count < matches.Count; count++)  
            {
                // extraer el valor del token
                var matchValue = matches[count].Value;

                // obtener del diccionario el valor de ese token
                // se remueven los signos - + para que el token coincida
                 dictionary.TryGetValue(Regex.Replace(matchValue,@"(-|\+)",""),out var value);

                // realizar la operacion correspondiente
                switch(matchValue[0]){
                    case '+':
                        total += value;
                    break;
                    case '-':
                        total -= value;
                    break;
                    default: // en caso no hay signo entonces se asume es una suma
                     total += value;
                     break;
                }                
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"El resultado es: {total}");
           

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var program = new Program();
            program.EvaluateExpression("-x1-x2+x3");
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry: debe ser un codigo mas general que acepte coeficientes de las variables

Comment: Lo sé. Resolví tu problema de no saber como evaluar las expresiones en tiempo de ejecución. Puedes modificarlo y agregarle los coeficientes.

Comment: Sorry, pero la expresión debe ser del tipo x01 no x1.Lo que pasa es que en realidad son mas de 10 variables por ello de esta forma. Una mas, si la expresión fuera x01*x02 + x03*x04 + 5/7*x05, como haría?

Comment: Lo de X1 0 X01 es trivial, solo se debe modificar la expresión regular. Parece que además debe soportar las 4 operaciones básicas y su jerarquía. Aquí hay un código en Java que evalúa expresiones del tipo : 2+3*5+6/3+3, puede servirte para complementar la solución 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/348163/55132

Comment: Lobo completalo por favor